# Toyota Corolla Maintenance light flashing

Tags: toyota, maintenance, oil-change, corolla, scheduled-maintenance

My Toyota Corolla 2013 maintenance light starts flashing (for 8 times) when I turn on my car. What does it mean?

Comment: Wild guess: scheduled maintenance required? When was the last maintenance done?

Comment: Yeah I think so. I had a oil change around Jun 1, 2018. Almost 5000 miles before.